Partially update an iOS Live Activity View from a push notification
I'm using ActivityKit on iOS 17 to show a Live Activity View. The user can update the LAV using a button on the LAV, and the LAV is also updated with push notifications. Here is what the LAV attributes look like:
struct NotificationLiveActivityAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        let event: String
        let counter: Int
    }

    let title: String
}

The button on the LAV updates the counter, and leaves the event state as it was using this:
    func update(newEvent: String?, newCounter: Int?) async {
        guard let activity = await activity else {
            return
        }
        

        let currentState = activity.content.state
        let newState = NotificationLiveActivityAttributes.ContentState(
            event: newEvent ?? currentState.event,
            counter: newCounter ?? currentState.counter
        )

        await activity.update(.init(state: newState, staleDate: nil))
    }

However, push notification updates have to update both event and counter or Swift throws an error when it tries to decode the content-state JSON in the push notification. How can I have the push notification only update event, and not change counter?
I tried making the ContentState properties nullable, and moving the logic in update(newEvent:newCounter:) into a view model, but the ActivityConfiguration struct that displays the LAV does not support the onChange modifier, so I can't figure out how to check the new content state and default to the old values where the new ones are null. The ActivityKit APIs also don't seem to support any kind of callback when new data is received from a push notification with an activity token.
